# Which PayPal Payment API should i select?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've tried PayPal payment standard, Website Payments pro for authorization and capture of payment. But what i need is authorize payment and capture it. But not all captured amount should transferred to my account. Instead some of my website fee should be deducted and that deducted amount should be added to my account. And receiver gets payments only when they send me a request to release their fund. My system works as like "User add any gift which he/she wants. His well wisher purchase the gift and pay through PayPal for it.After that admin will capture the fund and then amount should be transferred to user until admin wants. But the problem is that all balance is transferred to admin's account."

Please steer me in right direction. Thanks.

Comment: See if [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) work for you. Hth

Comment: Think about how you want liability to work and what you want the buyer experience to look like in both the normal path and exception cases. While I don't know your business, I strongly suspect that you may be better suited by having the payments go to you, then using a separate payment (e.g. MassPay) to pay the receiver when the receiver agrees to receive the payment.